# HTML divTable divTableCell side borders not showing

Tags: html, css

This should be ridiculously simple, however having tried on 2 separate servers it still doesn't appear to render correctly, so there must be something wrong with my code that I'm missing.

In short, a table of nested tables is created 'on the fly', but to keep things simple I've just pasted a sample of the static HTML page below.

For some reason, I can't get the right & left borders to show for the divTableCell's. I can't see any obvious error's so I presume I'm missing something that needs to be set at the table level perhaps?

```css
.divTable {
  display: table;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.divTableHeading {
  display: table-header-group;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.divTableRow {
  display: table-row; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.divTableHead div.divTableCell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<body>


<div id="market">
<div class="divTable">
<div class="divTableBody">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">
<div class="divTable">
<div class="divTableBody">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell"><div>"event_name"</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div>"event 1"</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div>"market_id"</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div>"1"</div></div>
</div></div></div></div></div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">
<div class="divTable">
<div class="divTableHeading">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableHead"><div>s_id</div></div>
<div class="divTableHead"><div>s_name</div></div>
<div class="divTableHead"><div>orders</div></div></div></div>
<div class="divTableBody">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell"><div>33</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div>E</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div>{"order_id":"77","price":140}</div></div>
</div><div class="divTableRow"><div class="divTableCell"><div>39</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div>D</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div>{"order_id":"87","price":130}</div></div>
</div></div></div></div></div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">
<div class="divTable">
<div class="divTableBody">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell"><div>"event_name"</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div>"event 2"</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div>"market_id"</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div>"2"</div></div>
</div></div></div></div></div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">
<div class="divTable">
<div class="divTableHeading">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableHead"><div>s_id</div></div>
<div class="divTableHead"><div>s_name</div></div>
<div class="divTableHead"><div>orders</div></div>
</div></div>
<div class="divTableBody">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell"><div>11</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div>A</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div>{"order_id":"99","price":150}</div></div>
</div></div></div>
</div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Apologies this is such a simplistic question and I am aware there are ton's of examples for this...but based on all that I've found this should work, so clearly I am missing something (possibly quite obvious)!

Comment: `box-sizing:border-box;`maybe ? aside `.divTableHead ` matching nothing here.

Comment: Thank you, the solution below worked, which I think is what you were also hinting at (i.e. removing the .divTableHead tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must remove `.divTableHead div` leaving only:

```
.divTableCell {
      display: table-cell;
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

it should work like this

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhh I knew it would be something ridiculously simple, many thanks!

For my understanding, why was my approach not working (I copied it from examples I found), can you not set multiple .div types using that syntax?

Comment: for multiple you would need a comma:

```
.divTableHead,
.divTableCell {
      display: table-cell;
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
}
```